# wordpress google fonts subset not showing characters

Tags: php, wordpress, google-fonts

I'm trying to embed this google font and add the subset latin-ext. Website is loading the font but it still does showing special characters from the subset.
This is in my functions.php:

```
wp_enqueue_style('google_fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Luckiest+Guy&subset=latin,latin-ext');
```

I'm not sure did i wrote font string right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `style.css`

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Luckiest+Guy&subset=latin,latin-ext);

No need to use `wp_enque_style()`

Hopefully you're using a child-theme so that you don't overwrite it next time you do a theme update.

Comment: yes it's working but for some reason it changed the font weight i think. I tried to add 400,700 and it looks like this @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Luckiest+Guy:400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext);